# How to write zend frame work standard validator between

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend framework standard validator code between I need to write in below format of Stringlength.

```
    validators.strlen.validator = "StringLength"
validators.strlen.options.min = 8
validators.strlen.options.max = 60
```

stringlength validator is working fine. Like this how I write "between" zend standard validator in my form.ini file?

Anybody know this? Please help me to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the ini config to create my forms, but that would definitely be something like this:

```
validators.between.validator = "Between"
validators.between.options.min = 8
validators.between.options.max = 60
validators.between.options.inclusive = true
```

Have a look at the [Zend Validator Between](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-validator/validators/between/) doc for options details.